# Copy account creation date time value to an extension attribute in Active Directory

Tags: string, datetime, active-directory, type-conversion, attributes

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that copies an AD user account's creation date and time value to the extension attribute 2 field in the user's account. Here's the contents of my script:

```
$users = get-aduser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=TestDC1" | Where-Object {$_.whenCreated -ne $null }| Select-Object Samaccountname,whenCreated

foreach($user in $users)
{
set-aduser -identity $user.Samaccountname -add @{extensionAttribute2=$user.whenCreated}
}
```

When I run the script, it fails with the following error:

```
set-aduser : Invalid type 'System.DateTime'.
Parameter name: extensionAttribute2
At C:\Users\admin\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts\Update_User_AccountCreation_Attribute.ps1:7 char:1
+ set-aduser -identity $user.Samaccountname -add @{extensionAttribute2= ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (john.sp.smith:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
   ands.SetADUser
```

I believe this is because extension attributes in AD only accept text-based values by default. How can I update the script to convert the account creation date and time value to a string that I can copy to extension attribute 2?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the `DateTime` to a string. You can do that with `.ToString()`.

```
set-aduser -identity $user.Samaccountname -add @{extensionAttribute2=$user.whenCreated.ToString()}
```

If you want to use a specific date format, you can read the [documentation for `ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tostring(system-string)).

Comment: Hi Gabriel, many thanks for the advice. That worked perfectly well!

Comment: Hi @gabrielluci, I'm trying to copy the account expiry attribute using the string conversion method you provided. However when I do that, I just see random numbers appear in the extension attribute field. How can I convert the account expiry attribute to a valid date time format and pipe this to the extension attribute field?

Comment: @MelBritIns It sounds like you're looking at the `accountExpires` attribute directly. PowerShell exposes an `AccountExpirationDate` property with a proper date.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, thanks again that's very useful to know. I've updated my script to target this attribute and convert the value to a string. If I wanted to run my script against number of select OUs in AD, how would I go about that? The search base filter I'm using doesn't appear to cater for multiple OUs.

Comment: No, the search base only accepts one value. You can either run the query multiple times for each OU, or filter the results after (ignore results where the `distinguishedName` does not contain the DN of the OU). The second way will probably run faster.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel, I'll see if I can add a filter to my script. Otherwise I'll just run the query multiple times as you've suggested,